# Авторизация по токену для POST/PUT/DEL в RESTful API на Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-security

Здравствуйте!
Впервые практикуюсь в REST и Spring.

Задача: создать простенький API, где всего 2 вида сущностей (посты и комменты к ним) и типичные задачи на создание (POST) и GET/PUT/DELETE по id сущности.

Без особых требований к БД и прочих нюансов, удалось без проблем построить такой сервис с помощью Spring Boot и БД H2. Протестировал на Postman - все отлично работает.

Сложности возникли с реализацией построением защиты. Необходимо реализовать авторизацию исключительно по токену, при этом авторизация для просмотра (всех GET запросов не нужна). Подключал Spring Security, создавал сущность юзера, имплементировал его в качестве автора рабочих сущностей, разделял роли и права на юзер/админ, в какой-то момент все работало (кроме ролей, так и не завел), но аутентификацию запрашивало всегда, включая GET.
Откатился назад. Может не с той стороны подхожу? Напомню, что со Spring работаю впервые.

Проект на Gradle, из интересного:

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
dependencies {
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
compile 'com.h2database:h2'
}
```

Структура проекта:

```
-com
  -entities
    -BaseEntity (abstract)
    -Post
    -Comment
  - repositories (интерфейсы, extends PagingAndSortingRepository)
    -PostRep
    -CommentRep
  - Application (@SpringBootApplication)
  - DatabaseLoader (implements ApplicationRunner, забивает БД сущностями для наглядности)
```

Подскажите возможные варианты реализации проблемы из заголовка. С чего начать, что и куда добавить? Или зря на Spring Boot делал?

Comment: а как настроена Spring Security?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Конкретно сейчас - никак, откатился до чистого REST, думаю может кто даст направление в другую сторону.

Comment: используя Spring Security можно сделать то, что вы хотите

Comment: Спасибо! Но остается открытым вопрос конфигурации настроек Security и нужно ли менять архитектуру проекта?

Comment: архитектура проекта и структура директорий - это разные вещи. если вы руководствовались принципами REST, то архитектуру менять не надо

Comment: если не трудно, дайте наводку на подходящие мне инструкции по настройке Security, пока копаюсь нахожу туториалы, примеры, но объясняется не для таких нубов как я или под чей-то конкретный проект, не совсем мне понятный

Comment: я бы рекомендовал начать с документации по [Spring Security](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/)

Answer (score 1):

Похожий вопрос [Spring Security. Разные права для разных пользователей. (Как скрыть для Коли (одного из юзеров) возможность «Создать пост» )?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766139/spring-security-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B4/784473#784473).

Для того, чтобы разрешить GET запросы без аутентификации, можно добавить следующую конфигурацию:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // ...
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll
    // ...
}
```

Spring Security добавляет к приложению цепочку фильтров (javax.servlet.Filter), их условно можно разделить на две части:

1. Устанавливают Authentication в SecurityContext;
2. Проверяют наличие необходимых ролей и прав по установленной Authentication.

Можно писать и добавлять свои фильтры в любое место этой цепочки. Например фильтр, который извлечет аутентификацию по токену:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    MyAuthenticationExtractorFilter filter = new MyAuthenticationExtractorFilter();
    filter.setMyUserDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);

    http.addFilterBefore(new MyAuthenticationExtractorFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
}

public static class MyAuthenticationExtractorFilter implements Filter{

    private MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService;

    public void setMyUserDetailsService(MyUserDetailsService myUserDetailsService) {
        this.myUserDetailsService = myUserDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        String token = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        UserDetails userDetails = myUserDetailsService.loadUserDetailsByToken(token);
        Authentication authentication = new Authentication() {
            @Override
            public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
                return userDetails.getAuthorities();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getCredentials() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getDetails() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public Object getPrincipal() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isAuthenticated() {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {

            }

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return userDetails.getUsername();
            }
        };
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Вот здесь хороший пример связки Spring Data REST и Security
https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/#react-and-spring-data-rest-part-5

(в комментах ответить не могу - не хватает репутации)

Comment: `не хватает репутации` — уже есть, можете скопировать ответ в комментарии и удалить его.