# Spring Security. Разные права для разных пользователей. (Как скрыть для Коли (одного из юзеров) возможность «Создать пост» )?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, spring, spring-security

**Делаю веб приложение на Java c использованием:**

- Spring MVC
- Spring Security
- Hibernate

**Распределение прав доступа к ресурсам/страничкам происходит через Spring Security. Есть три роли:**

- User
- Admin
- SuperAdmin

**Хочу чтоб админ мог редактировать права пользователя обычных юзеров, напр.:**

- юзер Вася может редактировать и создавать посты
- юзер Коля может    редактировать, а создавать нет

Что Коля что Вася - это роль User....

**Вопрос:** как скрыть для Коли возможность "Создать пост"? Какие есть способы реализации данного функционала?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пост - это единственный доменный тип и операции с ним сводятся к CRUD, то очевидным решением будет создание ролей *Editor* и *Writer*. Юзеру Васе назначаете Writer'а, а Коле Editor'а, и тогда в контроллере:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/posts")
public class PostController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('WRITER')")
    public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute Post post, BindingResult result) {
        ...
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('EDITOR')")
    public String update(@Valid @ModelAttribute Post post, BindingResult result) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Если же помимо постов есть комментарии, теги, профили и масса других типов данных, каждый из которых со своим набором операций, права на которые надо назначать гибко, вплоть до разрешения на конкретную операцию с конкретным объектом для конкретного пользователя, то придётся написать свой [PermissionEvaluator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/PermissionEvaluator.html):

```
@Component
public class SomePermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth,
            Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {

        // Возвращаем true если auth имеет permission на targetDomainObject
    }

    ...
}
```

объявляем его в конфигурации

```
<bean id="expressionHandler"
  class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
    <property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="SomePermissionEvaluator"/>
</bean>
```

и тогда на методы контролера можно навешивать более сложные проверки:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#post, 'edit')")
public String save(@Valid @ModelAttribute Post post, BindingResult result) {
    ...
}
```

Какую конкретно проверку выполнять в `PermissionEvaluator.hasPermission()` - решать вам, в зависимости от особенностей логики приложения. Например, можно объявить сущность привилегии:

```
@Entity
public class Privilege {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "privileges")
    private Set<User> users;

    ...
}
```

расширить [User](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html)

```
public class PrivilegedUser extends User {
    ...

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Privilege> privileges;

    public boolean checkPrivilege(String privilegeName) {
        return privileges.stream()
                         .map(Privilege::getName)
                         .anyMatch(i -> i.equals(privilegeName));
    }

    ...
}
```

объявить свой [UserDetailsService](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html):

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class PrivilegedUserDetailsService extends JdbcDaoImpl {
    @Override
    public PrivilegedUser createUserDetails(String username, UserDetails userFromUserQuery, List<GrantedAuthority> combinedAuthorities) {
        return new PrivilegedUser(userFromUserQuery, combinedAuthorities, fetchPrivileges());
    }
}
```

и тогда проверка сводится к

```
@Override
public boolean hasPermission(Authentication auth,
        Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {

    if (!auth instanceof PrivilegedUser)
        return false;

    PrivilegedUser user = (PrivilegedUser) auth;

    // Для простоты примера не учитываю targetDomainObject

    return user.checkPrivilege((String) permission);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно - буду ковыряться в PermissionEvaluator.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь вы можете прочитать про основы Spring Security https://habrahabr.ru/post/203318/.

Обратите внимание на интерфейс UserDetails. В нем присутствует метод:

```
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities();
```

Для примера возьмем такую реализацию этого метода:

```
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_USER", "EDIT_POST", "CREATE_POST");
    }
```

Теперь у вас есть возможность контрольровать доступ разными способами:
1.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // ...
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/posts").hasRole("USER")
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/posts").hasAuthority("CREATE_POST")
    // ...
}
```

Главное отличие hasRole и hasAuthority в том, что hasRole ищет из списка Authorities те, которые имеют префикс "ROLE_", зетем отбрасывает префикс и сравниваент.
2.

```
@GetMapping("/posts")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
public void getPosts(){...};

@PostMapping("/posts")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('CREATE_POST')")
public void createPost(@RequestBody Post post){...};
```

Полезная информация про различия role и authority http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-granted-authority-vs-role