# Права у юзеров (разные возможности на одной и той же странице). Для ролей исп. Spring security. Как это делается?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

**Есть три пользователя и у каждого одни и те же права:**

- Ваня: Создавать посты, Редактировать посты, Писать коменты, Лайкать
  посты
- Серега: Создавать посты, Редактировать посты, Писать коменты, Лайкать
  посты
- Олег: Создавать посты, Редактировать посты, Писать коменты, Лайкать
  посты

Но вдруг Ваня провинился и админ хочет отключить ему возможность "Писать коменты".

**Как это делаеться? Какие технологии использовать? 
В проекте исп. Spring security, Spring MVC, Hibernate**

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Spring Security. Разные права для разных пользователей. (Как скрыть для Коли (одного из юзеров) возможность «Создать пост» )?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/766139/spring-security-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4)

Comment: Здесь спрашиваеться о возможных технологиях и общих принцыпах разработки данного функционала. В прошлом вопросе же интересовала реализация на Spring Security.